# Rdlc report vertical barcodes

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have a problem in rdlc report in Visual Studio 2019 printing barcodes (2of5 or 3of9). In horizontal mode they are all OK, but in vertical property (`WritingMode`), the barcode does not show all bars correctly.

In design mode on screen, with a static barcode, all looks OK. But when is printed in PDF or on paper the barcodes have different struct. I try set `DpiX` and `DpiY` in `DeviceInfo` string to 1200 but nothing change. Is this an exist any bug? Any help?

Sample of barcodes:

[sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DptkR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, when something does not visualize on rdlc, it's usually a matter of size of the control placed on the report.

If the barcode you're trying to print is too big for the control size you set, then it will be removed by rdlc.

Try to test this by putting the barcode control in an empty area of the report and making it quite big and see if the barcode appears.

The elements you provided at the moment are insufficient to understand what actually is happening.

Comment: Updated the sample barcodes image. Same font and same barcode.I try with diferents size and it's the same.